# android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.setText Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android

I have this error in Fabric crashlytics with one of my Users "Fatal Exception: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:setSpan (-1 ... -1)` starts before 0" on this file `AccessibilityNodeInfo.java`, but I don't have this class on my project! What can I do to solve it ?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (-1 ... -1) starts before 0
       at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1326)
       at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:682)
       at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:674)
       at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.setText(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:2574)
       at android.widget.TextView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(TextView.java:10803)
       at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:7699)
       at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:7658)
       at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:7643)
       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1147)
       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1170)
       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1170)
       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1170)
       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchAccessibilityNodeInfos(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:972)
       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:336)
       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.access$400(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:67)
       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1324)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Before trying to solve it, you need to understand the problem. What are you trying to do? Can you add your code snippet and logcat?

Comment: I have a big application, I just  uprgade gradle 3.4.0 and I add  implementation 'com.droidninja:filepicker:1.0.0'  to pick file. I have this problem with my user phone: pixel 2 pixel 3 sony xperia xz1 compact and Samsung S9.

Comment: You need to add the class where this exception is thrown in? You also need to explain what your particular problem you are trying to solve and attach the logcat so people can have a clue what is going on. From what you shared so far, it is very hard if not impossible to figure out what your problem is and as such, people are simply going to ignore your question. I guarantee you that.

Comment: @RédaYoussoufi Did you get any hint?